# Is there a way to add custom passive scans to zap's active scan?

Tags: security, owasp, zap

In zap's UI there's the `scripts` view where you can define self-made scripts/use community created scripts. While you can create `Passive Rules`, I haven't seen a way how to include these scripts in the `Active Scan`. When manually sending requests the `Passive Scan` rules create alerts but when running the `Active Scan` it doesn't create any alerts from the user defined scripts (if that's what you can call them).

If anyone has an idea how to do add user defined scripts to the active scan, way around, or could point me to the documentation that explains this I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are 2 different things. You can define both passive and custom scripts and both can raise alerts. The passive scripts will run on all requests send by or through ZAP.

For ZAP example scripts see https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts
Also search for a tag of "scripts" on https://www.zaproxy.org/videos-list/

Comment: Sorry for the late response, have to take more look into those, thanks!